# How to show captured pieces in Arena?

Tags: software, arena, windows

I'm using Arena 3.5 on Windows. When playing, I want to see a list of the captured pieces beside the board in Arena. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a checkbox for it:-

Options | Appearance | View *tab* | Material difference

You may need to make the opening classification panel taller and then use the splitter on its left to see the material difference panel.

[image]

Comment: yes that is one way, but not exactly all captured pieces.